# Binding specific container to specific physical interface

Tags: docker, routes, iptables

I'm struggling with Docker for almost a week.

**Setup:**

```
eth0 - 192.168.1.0 - default
eth1 - 192.168.2.0 - secondary
docker-network - 172.20.0.0
```

When I trigger `curl https://ifconfig.me/` on the host machine I'm receiving IP for `eth0`

**What I want to achieve**

I want a container with static IP `172.20.0.100` to trigger curl requests via the `eth1` interface.

**What I've tried**

I've added the following:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -p all -s 172.20.0.100 ! -d 172.20.0.100 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.2.1
```

But when running:

```
docker run --rm --network docker-network --ip 172.20.0.100 byrnedo/alpine-curl -m 10 https://ifconfig.me/ip
```

It results in a timeout.

Surprisingly when I will swap the `eth1` IP with an `eth0` IP like this

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -p all -s 172.20.0.100 ! -d 172.20.0.100 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.1
```

The result is as expected so I'm receiving IP for `eth0`

Would you mind advising me on what I'm missing?